# What is meant by an 'integration dataset' in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm new to Synapse. I am using 'Azure Synapse' and I have noticed that there is an option to import an 'integration dataset'.

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly it means and how it differs from some of the other options for instance. I can't find anything on the Microsoft documentation. Can anyone please explain to me what it means?.

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration Datasets in Synapse are similar to Datasets in Azure Data Factory.
It is a reference dataset to specify the location and structure of your data within a data store which can be used in your pipeline activities and dataflows. There are many types of datastore options and connectors available to create your datasets which can be internal to Azure or external.

Please read this link to know more about datasets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services?tabs=data-factory